# Неявное приведение указателя на функцию к void * в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть такой код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int func()
    {
        cout << "func" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        void * p;

        p = func;
        cout << p << endl;
        cout << func << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

В Visual Studio 2010 данный код прекрасно компилируется и в обоих случаях выводит некоторый адрес.

Вопрос 1. Разве есть неявное преобразование, которое позволяет преобразовать функцию (указатель на функцию?) в тип `void *`?

Вопрос 2. Почему при передаче функции в качестве аргумента перегруженному оператору `<<` компилятор снова преобразовал функцию (указатель на функцию?) в тип `void *`, а не, скажем, в `bool`? Ведь неявное преобразование, позволяющее преобразовать указатель в тип `bool` есть.

Comment: Нестандартное поведение из разряда "это было давно и неправда".

Comment: @AnT: Ну, Visual Studio 2017 _без_ ключа `/Za` всё ещё компилирует. Обратная совместимость и всё такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код не компилирует [ни gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/yr1tUd), [ни MSVC](https://godbolt.org/g/oum6DB) в режиме с отключенными Майкрософтовскими расширениями языка (`/Za`).

Так что это и не должно компилироваться. Ну а почему неправильный код MSVC компилирует так, а не иначе — подробности их внутренней реализации, думаю. В режиме совместимости со стандартом (`/Za`) строка

```
cout << func << endl;
```

вызывает конвертацию в `bool` и вывод значения `1`.

---

Насколько я понимаю, по стандарту нет разрешения преобразования указателя на код в указатель на данные [в частности] потому, что на разных платформах эти указатели могут иметь разную длину.

Список всех возможных преобразований есть [в стандарте](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv); преобразование указателя на функцию в указатель на `void` там просто не упомянуто. Самое близкое, что там есть, это [7.11/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#ptr-2):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`”, where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `void`”. The pointer value is unchanged by this conversion.

Это правило позволяет конвертировать указатель на объект в указатель на `void`, но не указатель на функцию.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что явное преобразование условно поддерживается: Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

Comment: @Croessmah: Ну это через `reinterpret_cast` только (да и то conditionally).