# Почему адрес функции, полученный через указатель, всегда равен 1?

Tags: c++, c++11, вывод

Я получил немного странный результат.

Если я напишу какое то простое выражение с указателем, например,

```
    int a = 10;
    cout << &a << endl;
```

то в консоль будет выведено что то типа 0x66fe1c, что похоже на адрес в памяти.

Но если я проделаю то же с указателем на функцию, я всегда получаю "1".

Пример:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void add(int a, int b){
        cout << a+b << endl;
    };

    void subtract(int a, int b){
        cout << a-b << endl;
    };

    void multiply(int a, int b){
        cout << a*b << endl;
    };

    int main(){

        void (*operations[3])(int, int) = {add, subtract, multiply};
        
        int length = sizeof(operations)/sizeof(operations[0]);

        for(int i=0; i<length;++i){
            cout << operations[i] << endl;
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

программа выведет

```
    1
    1
    1
```

То есть, массив указателей на три разные функции содержит три одинаковых, и не похожих на адреса в памяти, значения.

В чем тут дело? что я делаю не так, и как получить "адрес функции в памяти"?

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: проверяйте перегрузку, вызываемую в `cout << operations[i]`

Comment: а зачем вы определяете размер массива, когда он у вас уже есть _ вы сами задали размер. А если хотите определить размер, std::size() вам в помощь

Comment: > а зачем вы определяете размер массива - справедливо! Пардон, поторопился

Comment: [Первый абзац в Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Неявное приведение указателя на функцию к void * в Visual Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/754865).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от компилятора. VC++, например, честно выводит адреса. GCC преобразует их в `bool`, как я понимаю (тут пусть гуру в стандарте скажут, верно это или нет).

Хотите оставить адреса - выполните приведение типов, в простейшем варианте как

```
cout << (void*)operations[i] << endl;
```

Полный код см. [тут](https://ideone.com/SShi32).

Comment: Clang тоже преобразует в `bool`. Обычно в таких ситуациях неправ оказывается MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано в документации https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt:

> There are no overload for pointers to non-static member, pointers to
> volatile, or function pointers (other than the ones with signatures
> accepted by the (10-12) overloads). Attempting to output such objects
> invokes implicit conversion to bool, and, for any non-null pointer
> value, the value 1 is printed (unless boolalpha was set, in which case
> true is printed).

То есть для указателей на функции нет специальной перегрузки и при попытке их вывода будет неявное преобразование к типу `bool`.

Comment: Спасибо, там выше, @Tocic уже указвал мне на этот абзац. Хотя, лично мне такое поведение кажется контринтуитивным.

Comment: @S.H. дополнил ответ

Comment: Типы передаваемых в функцию `std::printf` аргументов (`boo`, `doo` — преобразуются в указатели на функцию) не соответствуют используемому спецификатору преобразования (Спецификатор `p` означает, что аргумент должен быть указателем на `void`). Поведение программы не определено.

Comment: @wololo разве не будет автоматического каста `(void*)`?

Comment: Нет, не будет. На каком этапе вы ожидаете каста к `void*`?

Comment: @wololo ок, вам верю. Сейчас удалю эту часть ответа. Получается нет переносимого способа напечатать адрес функции?

Comment: Предполагаю, что на практике явный каст (`reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo)` или `(void*)foo`) будет работать всегда. Полученный указатель уже можно будет вывести через `cout` или `printf`. Однако, стандарт не требует обязательной поддержки такого преобразования. См. [expr.reinterpret.cast/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8). Привести пример реально существующего компилятора, который бы не позволял кастовать указатель на функцию в `void*` я не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо!

Про приведение к bool - я бы сам точно не догадался.

По меньшей мере, gcc может добраться до адресов так:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int boo(){
        return 7;
    };

    int doo(){
        return 8;
    }

    int main(){
        
        cout << "boo addr = "<< reinterpret_cast<void*>(boo) << endl;
        cout << "doo addr = "<< reinterpret_cast<void*>(doo) << endl;

    }
```