# Где в памяти располагаются функции-поля классов?

Tags: c++, функции, классы, объекты, адрес

Разбирался с классами и стало интересно,как и где хранятся функции-поля классов.
Если получить размер класса,то размер будет равен сумме размеров ***всех нестатических полей*** + выравнивание.
Не совсем понимаю,где тогда размещаются функции классов и их статические поля.Или для каждого класса будет своя функция или для всех классов используется 1 функция-поле класса?

Так же пытался найти адрес функций,но не получилось:

```
class myclass {
 public:
    int a;
    float b;
    static int c;

    int func1() { a = 4; return a; };
    int func2() { a = 6; return a;};
};

int myclass::c;

int main()
{
    myclass a1;
    cout <<sizeof(myclass)<< endl; //8 байт
    cout<<"addr class: "<< &a1 <<endl;         //67C5DDF7A0

    cout << "addr a class: " << &a1.a << endl; //67C5DDF7A0
    cout << "addr b class: " << &a1.b << endl; //67C5DDF7A4
    cout << "addr b class: " << &a1.c << endl; //7FF6866996A0

    cout << "addr func1 class: " << &myclass::a << endl;     //1 (Что мы получаем?)
    cout << "addr func1 class: " << &myclass::func1 << endl; //1 (Что это?)
    cout << "addr func2 class: " << &myclass::func2 << endl; //1

    cout << "addr func1 class: " << &a1.func1 << endl; //ошибка компиляции (Интересно почему?)
    cout << "addr func2 class: " << &a1.func2 << endl; //ошибка компиляции
}
```

Comment: [Почему адрес функции, полученный через указатель, всегда равен 1?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1154356/398802)

Comment: "Если получить размер класса,то размер будет равен сумме размеров всех нестатических полей" - не совсем... Дело в том, что есть такая вещь как выравнивание, так что для того, чтобы гарантировать данное утверждение нужно использовать директиву `pragma pack`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch точно,исправил)

Comment: @Whitehorse `как и где хранятся функции-поля классов` - там же где и обычные функции. Для каждого объекта не создаются отдельные функции, а просто используются одни и те же функции для всех объектов одного класса, при вызове в функцию передается указатель на объект (аналог this), через который происходит обращение к нестатическим полям объекта. Статические поля выглядят просто как глобальные переменные.

Comment: @insolor спасибо за ответ, но про глобальные переменные ,по моему плохая аналогия

Comment: @Whitehorse почему плохая? Статические поля класса по сути и являются глобальными переменными, просто доступ к ним ограничен средствами языка.

Comment: @Whitehorse нормальная аналогия, просто они находятся в области видимости класса + спецификатор доступа

Comment: Тип адрес метода/переменной внутри класса несовместим с типом `void*`. Даже по размеру 128 против 64. Этот тип является внутренней структурой реализации компилятора. Вывод в консоль данной структуры в стандарте не определён.

Comment: а как тогда получить адрес функции-члена?

Comment: `cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Class::func) << endl;`?

Comment: @EOF интересно,а почему (void*)&Class::func вот так не работает,ведь такое преобразование в итоге выбирает одно из подходящих и должно в итоге выбраться ваше?Разве не так?

Comment: Если честно, то я сам не уверен работает ли это корректно. Но вот [здесь](https://ideone.com/qb7r29) работает.

Comment: `int ( myclass :: * method_pointer ) ( void ) = & myclass :: func1 ;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe все а смысл?)

Comment: Вы спросили как узнать адрес функции.

Comment: @AlexGlebe а что толку от того что мы создали указатель на функцию?И чем она отличается от уже существующего указателя на функцию?От того что мы создали указатель,нам не проще стало получить адрес функции

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функции классов - это просто код. Который при вызове невиртуальных функций известен сразу, так что его (его адрес, точнее) никуда не надо включать, он разрешается при компиляции.

Если это виртуальные функции - то их адреса хранятся в таблице виртуальных функций и опять же эта таблица одна на класс, так что в каждый объект добавляется только указатель на нее.

Поэтому функции ничего (почти ничего - указатель на vtable для виртуальных) в размер класса не вносят.