# Влияют ли встроенные в класс функции на размер класса в оперативной памяти

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть класс:

```
class TestClass1{
public:
    char a;
    int b;
    std::string c;
}
```

И есть класс:

```
class TestClass2{
    private:
        char a;
        int b;
        std::string c;
    public:
        char GetA() {return this.a;}
        int GetB() {return this.b;}
        std::string GetC() {return this.c;}
    }
```

Если я составлю `std::vector<TestClass1>` и  `std::vector<TestClass2>` из 10^15 элементов каждый - будет ли их размер одинаков или различен?

И что происходит с функциями класса при хранении?

Comment: Ну сравните sizeof этих классов, сообщите результаты.

Comment: @user7860670 sizeof предоставляет размер класса по переменным, в нем содержащимся. Если размер все же различен в оперативной памяти, вычислить это sizeof будет невозможно

Comment: sizeof возвращает кол-во байт занимаемых объектом, не?

Comment: Сделайте массив из двух элементов TestClass. Выведете разность адресов первого и второго элементов - она совпадет с размером TestClkass

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл ну... по идее да. Но тогда я не понимаю, куда пишутся данные о функциях в классе

Comment: Ну а куда пишутся данные об обычных функциях? Функции в классе это такие же функции кмак и все остальные, просто синтаксис вызова немного другой + есть скрытый аргумент this

Comment: Функции лежат в виде машинного кода в исполняемом файле. Как максимум, в класс может попасть указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций (которые в этом примере отсутствуют). С++ не предоставляет средств рефлексии и информация, о том, какие функции или поля относятся к классу в исполняемом файле не содержится.

Comment: [Где в памяти располагаются функции-поля классов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1175604/413516)